# Hybrid Mobile App online Database

Tags: database, angularjs, cordova, ionic-framework, hybrid-mobile-app

I'm currently building a Hybrid mobile app using ionicframework,angularjs and cordova,in my app i will need some data storage such as all users details.
What i'm trying to figure out is how to update the database for all users,for example if a new user signs up,he should be added to the database and everyone else should be able see his profile instantly,i'm thinking the database should be shared online instead of just updating the local database installed with the app,i'm currently using SQLite plugin to store such data but i'm not sure if it's the right choice for my case.

Does anyone know how to reach what i want ? i would appreciate any help.

Thanks.

Comment: When the user finished sign up you can make ajax call and store data on remote server and you will sync your app on remote server particular time interval.

Comment: would that allow me to use relational data ?

Comment: as one more option to consider, you could try FireBase or similar that will handle all the authorization logic and keeping sessions for you, bonus 0auth with google, facebook, twitter

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thank you guys,after a lot of research,few days ago i decided to use Firebase,it's really powerful and works perfectly with angularJS and ionicframework which i'm using to build my app. I would really recommend it in situations similar to mine.

Answer (score 0):

Too many users then no point in storing and syncing. Creates more data inconsistency issues and resource consumption.

Online is the way to go.

If there is a subset of users whom u want to store information then thats an option.

Like watsapp stores and syncs information of those who are on your contact or chats only and not the whole watsapp db.